# Python subprocess.call() returning null response in lambda function AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, subprocess, command-line-interface

I need to run a CLI command that makes a recursive copy of folders inside a bucket and sets the ACL as "bucket owner full control".
Locally the function ran correctly.
But I need to test in the AWS console to go up to productive environment.
When testing in lambda service with the following code:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    subprocess.call(['aws', 's3', 'cp', '--recursive', '--acl', 'bucket-owner-full-control', 's3://bucket1/db1', 's3://bucket1/db1'], shell=True)
```

I just get a **response = null** and the change I want doesn't happen inside the bucket (nothing happens).

Is it possible to run this subprocess module inside AWS Lambda?

**This is the print of response in AWS console:**

[image: Image of respose]

Comment: How have you installed the aws cli in the Lambda Execution Environment?

Comment: @AnonCoward I didn't install this in Lambda. I use this subprocess module to run CLI commands. But if you refer to the AWS CLI locally, I installed it in a normally in my pc, get the environment credentials and everything is working perfectly.

Comment: The Lambda Execution Environment does not include the AWS CLI by default, so you can't run it without installing it as part of the package.

Comment: I read a lot of material about running CLI command in Lambda, and it takes a lot of configuration and package installations.
I decided to run in an ECS. I gave up on Lambda also due to the execution timeout (my application will take a lot of time to process the data). Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Your `lambda_handler` does not return anything. You have to add **return** statement to your handler.

But even if you do it will not work, as lambda does not have AWS CLI. You should be using [AWS boto3](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) to interact with S3 in your lambda.

Comment: I tried the return statement and got nothing yet. The boto3 would work, but I finally decided to apply the CLI command inside a python code in ECS (and I got it!), also because my application will take time to run the data and the Lambda has a 15-minute limit. Thanks for the insight.